# How to use cygwin perl v5.8.7 to support Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm

Tags: excel, perl, cygwin

I have the following Perl file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -

use strict;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

open (TABFILE, 'a.txt') or die "a.txt: $!";

my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('tab.xlsx');
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

# Row and column are zero indexed
my $row = 0;

while (<TABFILE>) {
    chomp;
    # Split on single tab
    my @Fld = split(',', $_);

    my $col = 0;
    foreach my $token (@Fld) {
        $worksheet->write($row, $col, $token);
        $col++;
    }
    $row++;
}
```

---

When I run in Cygwin, I have the following Error message:

```
Can't locate Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm in @INC (@INC contains: 
/usr/lib/perl5/5.8/cygwin 
/usr/lib/perl5/5.8 
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8/cygwin 
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8 
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8/cygwin 
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8 
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8/cygwin 
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8 
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8/cygwin 
/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8 .)
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: can you format your question description to understand

Comment: I create a test.pl file and use the : use strict; use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;  and then I Run my test.pl file on cygwin that raised the error message :  Can't locate Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/5.8/cygwin /usr/lib/perl5/5.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8/cygwin /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8/cygwin /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8/cygwin /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8/cygwin /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8 .)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You may want to add more information to your question, such as, have you installed [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Spreadsheet::WriteExcel)? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to use perl to implement => read the .txt file and save into .xslx file, the code like following : #!/usr/bin/perl -
 
use strict;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
 
open (TABFILE, 'a.txt') or die "a.txt: $!";
 
my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('tab.xls');
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();
 
my $row = 0;
 
while (<TABFILE>) {
    chomp;
    # Split on single tab
    my @Fld = split(',', $_);
 
    my $col = 0;
    foreach my $token (@Fld) {
        $worksheet->write($row, $col, $token);
        $col++;
    }
    $row++;
}

Comment: Install the module (`cpan  Spreadsheet::WriteExcel`). But first consider upgrading your Cygwin and Perl. The version of Perl you are using is ANCIENT! (It's 15 year old!)

Comment: Do you have better idea to use the version of perl to read/write Excel file ? Thank you very much !

Comment: [strawberryperl](http://strawberryperl.com/)

Answer (score 2):

The error message shows that you do not have Spreadsheet::WriteExcel module.

In Cygwin you can install this module with:

```
$ perl -MCPAN -e shell
cpan> install Spreadsheet::WriteExcel
```

If you decide to use Strawberry Perl you may install the module with:

```
cpan Spreadsheet::WriteExcel
```

Comment: Thanks~ But it still does't work. I use the command line to install it that failed.I don't know why .

Comment: @Xiali Did you get some error after trying to install module with cpan? Also you may check if you have multiple Perl versions with command `where perl` as it will find every occurrence of Perl in your path. Sometimes it might cause problems trying to use the module.

Comment: @zubenel yes, I got some errors,In fact, I have installed the strawberry Perl and the Cygwin. But, I want to open the cygwin and to run my perl script.and I install the cpan Spreadsheet::WriteExcel  on the cygwin . cpan> install Spreadsheet::WriteExcel
CPAN: Storable loaded ok
Going to read /cygdrive/c/Users/xiali/.cpan/Metadata
Warning: Found only 0 objects in /cygdrive/c/Users/xiali/.cpan/Metadata
CPAN: LWP::UserAgent loaded ok
Fetching with LWP:
  ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
LWP failed with code[501] message[Protocol scheme 'ftp' is not supported]

Comment: @Xiali Unfortunately I do not know how to help. You may try to search by copying error message and checking if someone else had a similar problem or create a new post detailing what have you tried to do and what the error message was. You can also try to ask on www.perlmonks.org

Comment: I believe your Cygwin perl is first in the path (you can check that with `which perl`). To change that, you can do rename **perl.exe** of Cygwin to something like **perl_cygwin.exe**. The Perl by default would then be Strawberry Perl (provided it is in the path).

Answer (score 1):

If the solution suggested by @zubenel does not work, you can use do it manually:

1. Download the `.pn` file from CPAN (https://metacpan.org/release/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/source/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm)
2. Copy it to the directory of your script in the path **Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm**
3. Run your scipt

(Note: this is not installing in your system so other scripts won't be able to use the module unless you copy it as well).